# sklearn StandardScaler, doesn't allow direct transform, we need to fit_transform

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

What is the difference between fit_transform and transform?
Why doesn't transform directly works?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

 X_scaler = StandardScaler()
 X_train = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
 X_test = X_scaler.transform(X_test)
```

If directly transformed it gives the below error

> NotFittedError: This StandardScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call
>   'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`StandardScaler`, as [per documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

> Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance

So it needs to somehow first know about the mean and variance of your data.
So `fit()` or `fit_transform()` is needed so that `StandardScaler` can go through all of your data to find the mean and variance. Those can be accessed 
by attributes:

> **mean_** : The mean value for each feature (column) in the training set.
>
> **var_** : The variance for each feature in the training set.

Note that those will be calculated separately for each column in the data.

In `transform()`, it will just use those `mean` and `variance` values to scale the data.

Now you might say that why just it don't calculate those attributes during `transform()`. This is done so that the test data is scaled in the same way as a training data is scaled (from `fit_transform()`). If you calculate mean and variance of data in each call to `transform()`, then all passed data will have different scale, which is not what you want.

This is true for all scikit transformers.

1) `fit()` - Will only go through the data and save all needed attributes of data

2) `transform()` -  Use the saved attributes from `fit()` to change the data

3) `fit_transform()` - Utility function to `fit()` and then `transform()` the same data.

Usually you would call `fit_transform()` on training data, and only `transform()` on test data.

Comment: Thanks , makes sense.